# Как правильно оформить сокращение при переводе: «от англ.» или просто «англ.»?

Tags: предлоги, переводы, оформление-текста, редактура

Если мы в научном или художественном труде хотим оформить перевод слова, как правильно писать: "от англ." (с предлогом) или просто "англ." (без предлога)?
Возможно, существуют какие-либо специальные рекомендации на этот счёт?
Приведу примеры, чтобы стало понятнее.

- *Персональный компьютер, или ПК (**от англ.** personal computer).*
- *Это называется лайфхаком (**от англ.** lifehack — букв. "взлом жизни").*
- *Слово "коворкинг" (**от англ.** coworking) в наши дни широко используется в бизнес-среде.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (25.12.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310208)):

> В специальных изданиях, где выбираются максимально экономные способы подачи материала, предлог перед названием языка-источника не дают (см., например, словарную статью «[Шопинг](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)»). В текстах для широкого читателя, в текстах, в которых нет установки на максимальную краткость, предлог обычно пишут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из МАС: предлог **от** употребляется при обозначении лица, предмета, явления и т. п., являющегося или послужившего источником чего-либо.
То есть при использовании предлога подразумевается, что мы хотим показать *от* какого английского слова произошло то, которое переводим.
При буквальном переводе, думаю, предлог не нужен.

Фонта́н (от лат. *fontana* в значении «источник», «родник», «ключ»);
«Фонта́н» (англ. *The Fountain*, оригинальное значение — «Исто́чник»).

Компью́тер (англ. *computer* — «вычислитель», от лат. *computare* — считать, вычислять);
персона́льный компью́тер, ПК (англ. *personal computer, PC*).

Коворкинг (англ. *coworking* — сотрудничество, совместная работа);
лайфха́к (англ. *life hack* — полезный, практичный совет или хитрость, помогающая сэкономить время).

В художественном тексте такая информация дается в сносках или в примечаниях.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу согласиться с этой формулировкой "Грамоты": *В текстах для широкого читателя, в текстах, в которых нет установки на максимальную краткость, предлог обычно пишут*.

Приведу примеры из моего любимого Рекса Стаута (англ. *Rex Todhunter Stout* — американский писатель, автор детективных романов; печатный вариант).
Ни в одном романе, ни в одной повести *внутри* самого художественного текста объяснений нет — они даются только в сносках. Предлог *от* в них употребляется в зависимости от значения (использования) того или иного слова.

• В одном из уголков владений миссис Рэкхем ему принадлежал небольшой клочок земли, Хиллсайд Кеннелз<sup>2</sup>, где он разводил породистых собак. <...>
................................
<sup>2</sup> Псарня на склоне (англ.).

•• Я выбрал имя Питер Трут, так как мне нравилось, что первый слог несет в себе некоторый подтекст<sup>1</sup>. <...>
...............................
<sup>1</sup> От англ. truth — правда.

В словарных статьях, на которые ориентируется "Грамота", — особое оформление: в них действительно глобально сокращается всё и вся.
[РЕЖИССЁР,](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80) -а; ***м.*** [франц. régisseur от лат. rego - управляю]...
Но даже в них, при всей краткости изложения, указывается, что слово пришло **из** французского языка, а образовано **от** латинского.

Comment: P. S. Не знаю, как оформить сноску под номером один. Кто может — подмогните, исправьте.

Comment: @athlonusm Спасибо большущее за правку, *athlonusm*. А секретик не раскроете — вдруг когда пригодится? С Новым годом!

Comment: Нужно написать `<sup>...</sup>`, где многоточие необходимо заменить нужной вам цифрой. Помимо цифр можно писать и слова. Эта функция аналогична надстрочному форматированию в Word. Чтобы сделать подстрочное форматирование, пишут `<sub>...</sub>`.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Запишу, чтоб не забыть.